# Emotions and discord reactions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want it when I add emoji as a reaction it sends a private message to who added.
Exemple:
https://youtu.be/tcBhXB4Kmqk

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the translator so the words may not make sense.

Comment: Can you maybe tell us what you tried already?

Comment: I tried doing it like it was a job but I could not. If you can send the code soon

Comment: Can you edit the code that you already tried in your question please

Comment: I want a code that does the same function I showed in the video. Click on emoji and the bot send private message

Comment: Yea but we don‘t tell you any code if you didn‘t try anything

Comment: We are not here to write this, what you should write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`client.on('messageReactionAdd', listener)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) to listen to the reactions.
Inside the `listener` function, you can check the message id & then send the message.
Here's a sample:

```
// let's say that the message ID is stored in my_id
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  // this is to avoid the bot sending messages to everyone that reacts anywhere
  if (reaction.message.id == my_id) user.send('Your message.');
});
```

You can also send different messages depending on which reaction was added: you can use [`ReactionEmoji.name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionEmoji?scrollTo=name) to check that.
To get the Unicode value of a built-in emoji, type the emoji with a backward slash (E.g.: `\:joy:` will result in ).

```
if (reaction.message.id == my_id) {
  if (reaction.name == '') user.send('Ayy lmao!11!!');
  else user.send('This is another emoji.');
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to use multiple emojis in a single message? How can I send a different message to each one?